# connecting a remote django app to postgresql on openshift

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, openshift

I have a django application running at a VPS. I just wanted to connect it to a postgresql instance I installed on openshift from redhat. In my settings file in the database settings, I have put the following -

```
########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'sdf',
        'USER': 'asdfsfpbb6c',
        'PASSWORD': 'dsfgsdgs1sbdeU',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

The trouble now is the HOST and PORT are 127.4.57.130 and 5432.
```

To get access to it locally I can always port-forward, but what if I want access to the database from another webserver, say a VPS? How can I achieve this?

```
stormydude@ubuntu:~$ rhc port-forward <app_name>
Checking available ports ... done
Forwarding ports ...
Address already in use - bind(2) while forwarding port 5432. Trying local port 5433

To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the Local address

Service    Local               OpenShift
---------- -------------- ---- -----------------
postgresql 127.0.0.1:5433  =>  127.4.57.130:5432
python     127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.4.57.129:8080

Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
```

Also, say if my server is on heroku, is there a way, I can connect to the db server at openshift?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a reverse port forward from OpenShift to your other server OR you can port forward from your server to the OpenShift server - but there is no direct DB access. Direct access would require exposing your database to the outside world and is generally considered bad security practice

Answer (score 1):

Use this blog for setting up port-forwarding with Red Hat command line tools (rhc)

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift

or you can manually run: ssh -N -L $YOUMACHINE_INTERNAL_IP:3306:$OPENSHIFT_REMOTE_INTERNAL_IP:3306 {appName}-{namespace}@rhcloud.com

Replace OPENSHIFT_REMOTE_INTERNAL_IP with the 127...* ip address

example:

ssh -N -L 10.11.22.213:3306:127.4.139.121:3306 test-testing@rhcloud.com